# Android - Dynamically added linearlayout not wrapping to height of children added later, dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, android-linearlayout

I am adding 7 linear layouts to a vertical linear layout, and in each one, I am looping through a cursor and adding a view that has two textviews vertically, for each row of the cursor.

Everything is working fine, except the linear layout is not wrapping to the content of the child view.

I had a feeling it's because I was setting wrap_content in the layoutparams before adding the child views, but I updated the linearlayouts layoutparams just before adding it to the main view and it still doesn't wrap.

Dynamically adding code

```
while(c.moveToNext()) {
    if(!(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")).equals(startDate))) {
        if(thisLin != null) {
            LayoutParams thisLinParams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            thisLin.setLayoutParams(thisLinParams);
            seven_wrapper.addView(thisLin);
        }
        thisLin = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

        // originally I was setting layoutparams here but I removed this
        // when I thought it wasn't wrapping properly as there were no child views
        // at this stage
        //LayoutParams thisLinParams = new LayoutParams(
        //  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //thisLin.setLayoutParams(thisLinParams);

        TextView t = new TextView(getActivity());
        t.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
        LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        t.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        thisLin.addView(t);
    }

    sevenItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seven_item, container, false);

    TextView time = (TextView) sevenItem.findViewById(R.id.seven_item_time);
    TextView name = (TextView) sevenItem.findViewById(R.id.seven_item_name);
    time.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")));
    name.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
    thisLin.addView(sevenItem);

}
seven_wrapper.addView(thisLin);

c.close();
```

Fragment View

```
<HorizontalScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/seven_day_rows_wrapper"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Child view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/seven_item_time"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/seven_item_name"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@id/seven_item_time"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was being an idiot.

My child view wrapped to parent, and the parent wrapped to the child, so it still remained the original size.

Changed the child to wrap_content on the height and it all worked.